# How to pass value to @Input Angular 8

Tags: angular

I want to pass the value through of the service

```
getSearchChange(event: string): void {
   this.searchChange.emit(event);
}
```

and in my component I have

```
@Input() set search(newSearch: string) {
  if (newSearch !== this.query) {
    this.query = newSearch;
  }
}
```

and my view I have

```
<div *ngFor="let pokemon of pokemons.results | search: query">...
```

but I'm getting error

How to pass value to "search" through service ?

Comment: Well what's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

in angular you need to use input as propery 
you need to do it like this in your html

```
<div *ngFor="let pokemon of pokemons.results" [search]="query" >...
```

in your component

```
@Input() search: T;
```

here `T` is type
for more details check out https://angular.io/api/core/Input

Comment: I dont can to use this way because I'm using a method of the filter, so I need to write this way : <div *ngFor="let pokemon of pokemons.results | search: query">

Answer (score 1):

You can use BehaviourSubject or subjects to push values and consume values. For Example

In your service class initializea BehaviourSubject variable and write a method to push values to it.

**service.ts**

```
    public searchChange: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
    getSearchChange(event: string): void {
      this.searchChange.next(event);
   }
```

And in component you can consume the value thats pushed into the BehaviourSubject as follows 
**component.ts**

```
    constructor(private service: Service) {
        this.service.searchChange.subscribe(value => {
             this.emittedValue = value;
        });
    }
```

I would recommend you to understand concept of observables and subjects.

Comment: I did it, but using EventEmitter and I get the value, but I would like of pass value to @Input set search(value),